# Which solution for Swapping ArrayList objects member with data in another - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Two possible solutions but which one? Or is there a Better?

I have a class MP3Track with members: Track number (int), track name (String), artist String), in faourites (boolean) etc. My catalogue class contains two ArrayLists, one containing all tracks (vectorMain) and the other containing fovuorites (vectorFav) which are copies of the tracks in the main catalogue.

I want the user to have the option of swapping two track numbers (which are unique in both arrays).

(Solution 1)
I have added the following code to do this and it works (if they exist - ATM) but it seems rather cumbersome. Surly there must be a better solution?

getMainIndex() - returns the index position in the ArrayList for a given track number or -1.

```
public void swapTrack(){
    int t1 = -1, t2 = -1;
    System.out.println(face.getSwapTrackMenu());       
    System.out.print("1) Please enter first track number to swap: ");
    t1 = scan.readInt();                                
    System.out.print("2) Please enter second track number to swap: ");
    t2 = scan.readInt();
    if((getMainIndex(t1)!=-1)&&(getMainIndex(t2)!=-1)){
        String s1 = null;
        String s2 = null;
        for(MP3Track track : vectorMain){
            if(track.getTrackNo() == t1){
                s1 = track.getTitle();
            }
            if(track.getTrackNo() == t2){
                s2 = track.getTitle();
            }
        }

        for(MP3Track track : vectorMain){
            if(track.getTitle().equals(s1)){
                track.setTrackNo(t2);
            }
            if(track.getTitle().equals(s2)){
                 track.setTrackNo(t1);
            }
        }

        for(MP3Track track : vectorFav){
            if(track.getTitle().equals(s1)){
                track.setTrackNo(t2);
            }
            if(track.getTitle().equals(s2)){
                track.setTrackNo(t1);
            }
        }
    }//End
```

(Solution2)

```
public void swapTrack(){
    int t1 = -1, t2 = -1;
    System.out.println(face.getSwapTrackMenu());       
    System.out.print("1) Please enter first track number to swap: ");
    t1 = scan.readInt();                                
    System.out.print("2) Please enter second track number to swap: ");
    t2 = scan.readInt();
    MP3Track mp31 = null;
    MP3Track mp32 = null;
    //But are these references or not?????
    for(MP3Track track : vectorMain){
        if(track.getTrackNo() == t1){
            mp31 = vectorMain.get(getMainIndex(t1));
        }
        if(track.getTrackNo() == t2){
            mp32 = vectorMain.get(getMainIndex(t2));
        }
    }
    mp31.setTrackNo(t2);
    mp32.setTrackNo(t1);
    vectorMain.add(vectorMain.remove(getMainIndex(t1)));
    vectorMain.add(vectorMain.remove(getMainIndex(t2)));

    for(MP3Track track : vectorFav){
        if(track.getTrackNo() == t1){
            mp31 = vectorFav.get(getFavIndex(t1));
        }
        if(track.getTrackNo() == t2){
            mp32 = vectorFav.get(getFavIndex(t2));
        }
    }
    mp31.setTrackNo(t2);
    mp32.setTrackNo(t1);
    vectorFav.add(vectorFav.remove(getFavIndex(t1)));
    vectorFav.add(vectorFav.remove(getFavIndex(t2)));
```

}

This is more elegant but also seems cumbersome to me.
Or is there something I'm missing here? I've hit a wall!!

I'm new to Java so any suggestions, improvements & comments appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: These types of questions are more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You may want to ask moderators to move it there.

Comment: First is my choice. It looks nicer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems excessively complex to me.

You ought to have two separate classes: `Catalog` for the universe of MP3s available.  Favorites seem like they should be associated with a `User`.  Multiple users should all be able to share a favorite from the `Catalog`, but the `Catalog` class need not know anything about it.

This method would be far more useful if you kept the IO out of it.  Move it into a driver class and then pass what's needed to the methods.